# Two subqueries in a with statement and a select statement for the outcome

Tags: sql

```
with pro_cra as (
  select p.productid 
  from production.product p 
  where p."name" like 'Crankset'
),  
add_lon as ( 
  select a.addressid
  from person.address a
  where city like 'London'
)
select sum(s1.orderqty) 
from sales.salesorderdetail s 
join sales.salesorderheader s1 on s.salesorderid = s1.salesorderid
join add_lon adl on s.billtoaddress = adl.addressid
join pro_cra prc on s.productid = prc.productid

;
)
```

Hi guys !

I know my problem is in the last join statements. I don't know what the solution is. Can anybody help?

Update! I deleted those select statements I had. I used to check the tables they werent relevant for the code.

### I get this message.

### SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "add_lon" does not exist
Position: 133

Comment: Hi - you haven’t provided any information about what the issue is, what you are trying to achieve, any error messages, etc. But if your issue is just that this is invalid SQL then you have unbalanced braces and 3 entirely distinct SQL statements, separated by the “;”

Comment: I formatted your code with just the smallest amount of removing tabs and indenting and instantly it is clear -- you have a random syntax at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with pro_cra as (
select p.productid from production.product p 
where p."name" like 'Crankset'),
add_lon as ( 
select a.addressid from person.address a
where city like 'London')
select sum(s1.orderqty) from sales.salesorderdetail s 
    join sales.salesorderheader s1 on s.salesorderid = s1.salesorderid
    join add_lon adl on s.billtoaddress = adl.addressid
    join pro_cra prc on s.productid = prc.productid;
```

removed the select * statements with semicolons and also moved the final semi-colon to its proper place.

Does this work?

Comment: Thanks! I did the changes to I get NULL value. I think the problem can be in the adress values because I dont know how to combine values from different schemas correctly. 

with pro_cra as (
select p.productid from production.product p 
where p."name" like 'Crankset'),
add_lon as ( 
select a.addressid from person.address a
where city like 'London')
select sum(s.orderqty) from sales.salesorderdetail s 
    join sales.salesorderheader s1 on s.salesorderid = s1.salesorderid
    join add_lon adl on s1.billtoaddressid = adl.addressid
    join pro_cra prc on s.productid = prc.productid;

Comment: hi @Serhat welcome to stackoverflow -- It is basically useless to add code to a comment like this because it is unreadable.  Please edit the original question or create a new one.